# Static Code Analysis using Java, JGit, PMD

Tags: java, csv, jgit, pmd

I am trying to clone the repository from the github, do a local clone and do static code analysis on the java source code. Finally write the results into the CSV file.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.lang.String.indexOf(String.java:2401)
    at java.base/java.net.URLStreamHandler.parseURL(URLStreamHandler.java:157)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.parseURL(Handler.java:56)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:801)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:654)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1091)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$FileLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:1079)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$1.next(URLClassPath.java:343)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$1.hasMoreElements(URLClassPath.java:353)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader$1.hasNext(BuiltinClassLoader.java:408)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader$1.hasMoreElements(BuiltinClassLoader.java:416)
    at java.base/java.lang.CompoundEnumeration.next(ClassLoader.java:2756)
    at java.base/java.lang.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(ClassLoader.java:2765)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1210)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1228)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:255)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:251)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:228)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:172)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createDocumentBuilder(RuleSetFactory.java:444)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:366)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:549)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:503)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am running a static code analysis using JGit, PMD and trying to write those results in a CSV file. But, I am continuously getting this error. I am not sure what exactly this issue is popping up. I have tried to change the custom-ruleset.xml.

**This is my custom-ruleset.xml.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ruleset name="Combined Ruleset"
         xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 https://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">

    <description>
        Combined ruleset including custom ruleset and others.
    </description>

    <!-- Reference the custom ruleset using relative path -->
    <rule ref="./custom-ruleset.xml"/>

    <!-- Additional rules -->
    <rule ref="category/java/bestpractices.xml/AvoidUnusedPrivateFields"/>

</ruleset>
```

Comment: If anything problem in github repo, create a issue in that repo. Hint: IPAddressUtil .java -> checkHostString() method has stackoverflow issue. raise the issue into that repo. we can't solve the github repo issue without understand their entire project

Comment: how about these errors ?

at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createDocumentBuilder(RuleSetFactory.java:444)
 at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:366)
 at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:234)
 at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:229)

Comment: @NewBeeBeginner - That is incomplete.  Put the **complete** stacktrace into the question.

Comment: @StephenC, I have added the entire stacktrace above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ... I see.  The stacktrace indicates that there is infinite recursion while loading a ruleset.  And ... apparently ... that is happening while loading your "custom-ruleset.xml" resource.

And that makes sense.  The file contains this line:

```
<!-- Reference the custom ruleset using relative path -->
<rule ref="./custom-ruleset.xml"/>
```

This is actually telling the loader to load "./custom-ruleset.xml".  But that is **this file**.  In other words you are loading your file recursively.

That is a bug in your ruleset.

Comment: how do I fix this infinite recursion which you mentioned?
<rule ref="./custom-ruleset.xml"/>

Comment: My guess ... remove that line.   I have no idea why the ruleset needs to reference itself.

Comment: Nov 18, 2023 6:16:46 AM net.sourceforge.pmd.util.log.internal.SimpleMessageReporter logImpl
SEVERE: Cannot load ruleset C:\Users\ummea\OneDrive\Documents\Wahid-OOPs\Implementation_Project\Static_Code_Analysis\custom-ruleset.xml: Unable to find referenced rule FinalParameterInAbstractMethod; perhaps the rule name is misspelled?
Nov 18, 2023 6:16:46 AM net.sourceforge.pmd.util.log.internal.SimpleMessageReporter logImpl
WARNING: No rules found. Maybe you misspelled a rule name? (C:\Users\ummea\OneDrive\Documents\Wahid-OOPs\Implementation_Project\Static_Code_Analysis\custom-ruleset.xml)

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://pmd.github.io/pmd/pmd_rules_java_codestyle.html), that rule was added in PMD 6.42.0.  What version are you using?

Comment: this is my pom.xml
 <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.40.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add the PMD dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.48.0</version>
        </dependency>
Which version am I supposed to use ?